# Was it necessary for Jesus to be identified by a disciple of His?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospels, judas-iscariot

Why did the Jewish leaders have to seek the help of Judas Iscariot in identifying Jesus for them ( Matt 26:49 ; Mark 14:45 ) . Is it that Jesus looked so similar to his disciples that  it was difficult to identify Him without the help of someone well-acquainted to Him ?  Or, is it that the Jewish leaders did not want to risk arresting the wrong person and thereby losing a second  chance (of arresting Jesus)  fearing a public commotion ?  What is the Roman Catholic view on the role attributed to Judas?

By the way, the Gospels do not quote any prophesy - of course, other than that of Jesus Himself - having been fulfilled by way of that betrayal, which has since been talked about all through human history.

Comment: That question doesn't ask for a Catholic view, but I doubt that there *is* an official Catholic view, and I doubt that there's a prevailing view among Catholics that differs significantly from that of other denominations.